# Modified ROI and then adding it to the original image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to Python and OpenCV. My task is to perform some operations on the ROI of an image and then adding back that image to the original image. How could I achieve this? For example, I want to change the colour of the ROI image and then add it back. My code is given below:

```
for (i,c) in enumerate(contours_from_left_to_right):    
     cv2.drawContours(duplicate_img, [c], -1, (0,0,255), 3)
     cent_moment = cv2.moments(c)
     centroid_x = int(cent_moment['m10'] / cent_moment['m00'])
     centroid_y = int(cent_moment['m01'] / cent_moment['m00'])
     cv2.putText(duplicate_img, str(i+1), (centroid_x, centroid_y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
     cv2.imshow('Contours from Left to Right', duplicate_img)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
     (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)    
     print("Top-Left Corner=",(x,y), "width= ",w,"height =",h)      
     ROI = roi_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]    
     cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
     image_number += 1
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the ROI in terms of changes? Use ROI as any other image and process it as you want. Then use numpy slicing to put it back. image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = ROI

Comment: Thank you so much, I am able to do my required task with the help of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you selectyour ROI,you will have (x,y). After you complete your image processing on the ROI image, you can save the image and use pillow to paste the roi image back to original image follows the coordinate of the ROI.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter

#test
im1 = Image.open(args["image"]) #Original Image
im2 = Image.open("ROI.tif") #ROI Image after process 
back_im = im1.copy()
back_im.paste(im2, (ROIRegion[region][0][0], ROIRegion[region][0][1])) #(x, Y) coordinate
back_im.save('replace.tif', quality=95) #save image
```